# Avoiding "is not recognized as an internal or external command" when running a .bat script with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I wrote a basic .bat script that you can find below:

```
@echo off
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip
{
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}
$import="E:\directory\import"
cd $import
Unzip $import\file1.zip $import\extract\
Unzip $import\file2.zip $import\extract\
Unzip $import\file3.zip $import\extract\
```

When I run these command lines directly into the PowerShell terminal (by copy-paste), it's working fine!

But, when I save all these command lines into a "test.bat" and - then - run this .bat file, it's not working :

[image: Errors messages]

Sorry, errors messages are in French, but it means "is not recognized as an internal or external command, executable program or command file" for each command line.

I've tried to run the .bat file from different ways:

1. `.\test.bat` directly into the directory from PowerShell terminal
2. `[FULL_PATH]\test.bat`
3. `powershell E:\directory\import\test.bat` from the CMD app
4. `C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe E:\directory\import\test.bat` from the CMD app
5. Etc.

And I still get the same error messages.

You can find below my Path configuration:

[image: Path config]

Comment: `.bat` is used for Cmd's batch files. Rename the file as `.ps1`, so it's being run with Powershell.

Comment: Note the `@echo off` is the only piece of code here that is only available to be used in a `CMD`/`BAT`ch Script.  You will need to remove that from the PS script to stop it from throwing some errors once you rename it `.ps1` further, you will need to make sure you have set your Powershell Execution Level to allow you running unsigned scripts in Powershell

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing batch scripting and PowerShell Scripting. You need to save your script as a `.ps1` file instead of a `.bat` and remove any cmd only commands.

> **test.ps1**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip
{
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}
$import="E:\directory\import"
cd $import
Unzip $import\file1.zip $import\extract\
Unzip $import\file2.zip $import\extract\
Unzip $import\file3.zip $import\extract\
```

The reason it works when copy pasting is because each command is interpreted independently and therefore can use different interpreters. However, this is not the case in a script in which the terminal must decide which interpreter to use. Based on the file extension, it chooses cmd. This only allows the `@echo off` to work and everything else will fail.